# Using MS Word Table Styles to Change Font Size

Tags: fonts, microsoft-word-2007, table-styles

I made a custom table style using MS Word 2007.  I set the font to be Arial 10pt and to apply to the whole table.  The font changed to Arial, but the font size of my table did not change.  When I go to Modify Table Style again the drop-down for the font size is blank (i.e. no size is selected).  Attempting to change the font size via the drop-down or Format->Font button has no effect.  Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: It should work, pretty much as you describe. As you change "Apply formatting to", you should see the modifications for each area. Maybe try just applying your change to the header row and see what happens?

Comment: Table styles used to work great in versions of Word prior to 2007.  I used office 2002 and 2003 for years without these kinds of problems.  Now, M$ has to go and break table styles.  I know it's not just my machine or document because I've experienced the same difficulty with table styles in Word 2007 ever since I started using it (multiple machines, multiple documents).  This junk software has been out for 4 years now, and they still haven't fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently a bug that Microsoft isn't going to fix.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem and generalized the explanations in [that question](https://superuser.com/questions/1241203/ms-word-priority-management-between-table-and-paragraph-styles/1241446#1241446).

For that specific question, it comes from the fact that the Internal Root Style (IRS) is TNR, 10 pts. If the Paragraph style applied to the text in the table differs from that, it will override whatever you set in the Table style.

The solution is then to set the Normal Style to 10 pts, which will avoid him to override the IRS. Then you'll have to deal with it and create your own styles if you don't want to use 10 pts Font in your text body. My advise would be to create a "My Normal" style, and make every styles which previously inherits from the Normal style inherit from "My Normal" style. Note that the paragraph style applied to the table must also be 10 pts.

Answer (score 1):

The quick way to handle this is before inserting the new table, change the paragraph style to Table Body. What happens is Word uses the style for the current paragraph to assign the fonts and spacing. By changing the style to the Table style (hopefully you've adjusted the specs on that style), Word will