# MS Word : Priority management between table and paragraph styles

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

Within a table, some parameters can be set in both the table style and the paragraph style.

How does Word manage priorities between those conflicting settings ?

I made some tests and the rule seems to be :

**Paragraph style > Table style when the parameters differs from the Normal style.**

For example, if I change the police in the table style it will apply to the table. If I then change the police in the paragraph style (which has been applied to all the text inside the table), it will also apply to the table. If I then change again the police in the table style, nothing happens.

Do I get the rule right ? Did I miss something ?

I am experiencing [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/260944/using-ms-word-table-sytles-to-change-font-size) that is I cannot change the police size (but every other police parameters are fine) via the table style. Hard for me to believe that the bug would still be there years later, but with a better understanding of the internal soup it may be possible to find a workaround.

Comment: My experience is that it works just as you described both in MS Word 2013 and 2016. This post might shed some light: http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=7865

Comment: Very useful thread, I think I understand it now. The "internal normal" seems to be the key, but there's no access to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that we're stuck with old dev choices, back in the days where object oriented thinking wasn't in the users' minds.

There is some kind of Internal Root Style (lets call it IRS) which is built-in Word and, as far as my research went, cannot be modified. Normal paragraph style inherits from him. The IRS is, for Font options :

*Time New Roman, 10 pts, no options.*

I will not detail other-than-font IRS format parameters but it's mostly every numeric parameter set to 0 and every tick box unchecked.

**Hierarchy of styles**

When formatting a text in a table, MS Word will do as follow :

- Applying IRS
- Applying Table style if it differs from IRS
- Applying Paragraph style if it differs from IRS

**Side notes**

1. Every options are handled separately.
2. If any Paragraph style in the style hierarchy up until the Normal style differs from the IRS, paragraph style will apply even if the final result ends up to be the same as the IRS.
3. When you apply "Bold" on an yet bold text, it goes back to
   normal. That exactly what happens here, so if Table style and
   Paragraph style says "Bold", text won't get bold. Same for "Italic",
   etc.
4. Tick boxes don't work as Bold-like parameters. They will be checked following the hierarchy without a look at their previous state. Most of the time that means "if it's checked somewhere, it will apply".
5. The police size "bug" comes from the fact that the Normal Paragraph Style from which every paragraph styles inherits is rarely 10 pts if you use Word default templates. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/260944/using-ms-word-table-sytles-to-change-font-size?noredirect=1&lq=1) for details. According to 2. you will have to make heavy changes in your styles hierarchy, you can't trick the software.

**Reference**

This answer has been made from the tests I made after reading [that thread](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=7865). I will conclude with a quote from there which perfectly sums up my thoughts :

> The real mistake in design, from my POV, is not being able to
>   assign paragraph styles to parts of a table. But heh, all anyone was ever asking
>   for before this was "personalized Table AutoFormat". Really. And that's exactly
>   what we got! Only, now that we have it, we're not satisfied...

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the answer from math3006:

When you start a new document and **don't** change the Normal style in that document, then it seems that the table style works properly. Meaning that changes in font size, paragraph spacing, etc. can be set in the table style and the corresponding tables will be updated.

However, if you start a new document and **do** change the Normal style, then the table styles don't seem to have any effect on the font and paragraph settings of the table content anymore. In that case, the table style will only be useful for design changes (e.g. shading color).

This all sounds similar to what math3006 said, but there is a very important information to add. You are not stuck with the default Times New Roman 10pt style. I've done some tests and if you update the Normal style in your Normal.dotm template and then start a new document, you won't have to update the Normal style in that new document anymore. Like that, you will be able to still use a different Normal style **and** have the table styles working.
So, the work around is:

1. Open the Normal.dotm file
2. Edit the Normal style to have your desired settings and save the Normal.dotm file
3. Start a new document and **don't** edit the Normal style (which you shouldn't have to, since you've already edited it in Normal.dotm template).
4. Create your custom table styles and apply them to your table